TV show: his roommate is a divorced puppet with a drinking problem
I'm trying to identify a series that I watched a few episodes of via streaming, on Amazon or (less likely) Netflix, in the past six months. I set it aside and now I can find no trace of it anywhere.
It's a sitcom whose main characters are a couple of unimpressive youngish guys living together.  One is played by a human actor and one is played by a Muppet-style puppet --- think Gary and Walter, but without any of the wholesomeness.  The puppet still carries a torch for his (human) ex-wife, who is a local news anchor and/or a supermodel. I don't remember whether there is more than one character who is a puppet.
In one episode the puppet drops by the ex-wife's house, and has an oblivious conversation through a glass door with the ex-wife and her current beau, who are dressed for some sexual adventure.
In another, the human lead character wants to have a tree removed from his neighbor's property because of an overhanging branch, or something.  Somehow the famous ex-wife catches wind of this and makes a public statement that removing trees is bad, so the puppet tries to impress her by chaining himself to the tree and preventing it from being cut down.  When the human lead finds the puppet chained to the tree they had agreed to remove, the puppet says something like "I'm so glad to see you. My perineum itches; can you scratch it?"  This tells you something about the tone of the series.
Search results are overwhelmed with Greg the Bunny, where the roommate is (incorrectly) an animal, and Avenue Q, which seems to have been been only on Broadway.

I found it: Sammy J & Randy in Ricketts Lane (also on imdb).

The ex-wife is always referred to as "Randy's ex-wife the beautiful Victoria Vincent" or some such locution, and she stars in a current-affairs TV program called "Thumbs Down with Victoria Vincent" where she complains self-righteously about things she dislikes.
The tree removal is episode 2, "Field of Dreams." The motivation for getting the tree removed is that it's interfering with Randy's peeping-Tom spying on his ex-wife the beautiful Victoria Vincent, but most of the characters don't know this reason.  Victoria Vincent finds out about the tree removal and gives it a thumbs down on environmental grounds, which changes Randy's mind.
